# Javascript in .net not working properly

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a document where i write this line of code for my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function OnMouseOverFunction(id) {


                     var value = id.id;

                     alert("welcome");



                     element1 = document.getElementsByName("Image1");
                     element2 = document.getElementById("Image2");
                     element3 = document.getElementById("Image3");
                     element4 = document.getElementById("Image4");
                     element5 = document.getElementById("Image5");


                     if (value == "ContentPlaceHolder1_Image1") {
                         id.src = "images/zvezda3.png";
                     } else if (value == "ContentPlaceHolder1_Image2") {

                         id.src = "images/zvezda3.png";
                         element1.src = "images/zvezda3.png";

                     }



                 }</script>
```

and these are the pictures below:

```
<b>Ocena:</b>
                 <asp:Image onmouseover="OnMouseOverFunction(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" name="1" ImageUrl="images/zvezda2.png" id="Image1" runat="server" /> 
                 <asp:Image onmouseover="OnMouseOverFunction(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" value="2" ImageUrl="images/zvezda2.png" id="Image2" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Image onmouseover="OnMouseOverFunction(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" value="3" ImageUrl="images/zvezda2.png" id="Image3" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Image onmouseover="OnMouseOverFunction(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" value="4" ImageUrl="images/zvezda2.png" id="Image4" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Image onmouseover="OnMouseOverFunction(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" value="5" ImageUrl="images/zvezda2.png" id="Image5" runat="server" />
```

If I remove the alert("welcome"); the picture is changed. but with the alert i get this error:

```
Property 'alert' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

My goal is to change 3 colors (to yellow picture) if a mouse position is on 3.image. etc...
But why is the alert not working?
Also i wonder, how can i get the element by its ID??

```
element2 = document.getElementById("Image2"); 
element2.id //it returns null
```

EDIT:

but the...

```
document.write("test");
```

...works fine!

Comment: View the page source, look at the ids of the images. Are they what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The 'id' attribute on server controls are only valid on the server, .net mangles the id when emitting HTML.

To fix this you need to get the ClientId for use in JavaScript .

Try
`document.getElementById('<%= Image5.ClientId %>');`

Replace the server id for each image

Comment: This was the case in pre .NET 4.0, but starting in ASP .NET 4.0 there are several configurable modes of id generation.  Check out the ClientIDMode attribute / property for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx